# GitHub pages serving from docs and jekyll source folder config

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

The documentation for standard F# (following ProjectScaffold) has the following structure

```
- project
| - docs
| | content
| | files
| | output
| | tools
```

The generated docs are saved into `output`, which are then pushed to the `gh-pages` branch.

Recently, GitHub has changed the way serving pages work and now you can just serve the `docs` folder directly from the `master` branch. The problem is that the actual folder I wish to serve is `docs/output`.

Jekyll has a `source` configuration that allow me to do this locally. My `docs/_config.yml` is just:

```
source: output
```

Which works fine if I run `jekyll serve` in the `docs` folder locally. But after pushing to GitHub, the pages are still served under `/output` prefix.

So apparently GitHub is overriding the `source` option. Is there anyway this can be worked out?

Comment: No. This question doesn't deserve a down-vote. It clearly illustrate the growing complexity of Jekyll / gh pages setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is Jekyll's documentation unclear. Yes.

New github pages publication branch/folder :

Available options are ([doc](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/)) :

- gh-pages branch
- master branch
- master branch /docs folder
- Disable GitHub Pages.

Three first options defines your root publication folder.

Github pages uses this root folder to generate your site. [You cannot override `source` key in your `_config.yml`](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-jekyll/#configuration-settings-you-cannot-change).

Your can store your sources in a _docs folder and output in docs

```
- project
| - _docs
| | content
| | files
| | tools
|
| - docs << output here
```