# How to set up GitHub Pages to look for index.html in a different location?

Tags: github, github-pages

Just set up my GitHub Pages website and as far as I can tell, GitHub Pages will look for index.html in the parent directory (i.e. if my repo is in username.github.io, it will look for index.html in username.github.io/index.html).

If it cannot find index.html there, it renders out my README.md on the page instead.

Must the index.html file go there or is there a way to tell Pages to look for that file in let's say username.github.io/src/index.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub has now made that easy.
When you try to deploy your project, don't deploy it from a branch. Instead, do that using the `GitHub Action` option.
Choose `jekyll`, then a file called `jekyll-gh-pages.yml`, will open and inside it, you'll need to change the source to whatever you want.

```yaml
jobs:
  # Build job
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v3
      - name: Build with Jekyll
        uses: actions/jekyll-build-pages@v1
        with:
          source: ./dist/  // CHANGE THAT TO WHATEVER YOU WANT
          destination: ./_site
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v2
```

This will make the default folder `./dist`.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer if GitHub added this feature in now, thanks for the post!

Answer (score 7):

You can try this: create a dummy index.html file at the root, and insert this line of code inside the head tag and give it the right path.

**index.html**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://yourname.github.io/myapplication/frontend/public/index.html" />
```

Note that the url is inside the content's quotations

Answer (score 2):

No.

You would need to change the site source to change the directory where Jekyll will read files, but this is a configuration setting that you cannot change in GitHub Pages:

https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-jekyll/#configuration-settings-you-cannot-change

You can, however, change the source to the `docs` folder in the settings of your GitHub repository.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41197820/2102854.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490), by [cobyism](https://gist.github.com/cobyism), you can use *[subtrees](https://git-memo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subtree.html)* (not to be confused with the [subtree merge strategy](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies#Documentation/merge-strategies.txt-subtreeltpathgt)):

```
git subtree push --prefix <your-path> origin gh-pages
```

---

from the *git-subtree* docs on [git's source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt#L20):

> Subtrees allow subprojects to be included within a subdirectory of the main project, optionally including the subproject's entire history.
>
> For example, you could include the source code for a library as a subdirectory of your application.